# Do I need to reinstall to upgrade regular Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu Gnome 13.04?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 13.04

My home server runs 12.10 with Gnome Shell (I'm not a fan of Unity). I can't find any information to tell me if the regular upgrade process will let me choose the Ubuntu 13.04 remix, or whether I need to go for a complete reinstall.

It took me a long time to get MythTV working in this environment, so an upgrade would be preferable!

Answer (score 0):

An distro upgrade means: *forget about this old release, and see this new one*

You will not *reinstall* any system, so you don't have to worry about partitioning or things like that.

You just press a button, turn off and on again, and the new release will be running the next time (a bit more complex some times)

Of course that you *can* have issues after update your distro version, but that really depends on each case scenario. But you have us for troubleshooting :)

---

Other options that you have is, install the new distro in a new partition, so if it doesn't work you still have Ubuntu 12.10 working. Also, you can make a *fresh installation*, installing the new system from the scratch in the actual Ubuntu partition.

You choice what method use

Comment: Remember that, if some of the answers has responds to your issue, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/62483) so this question remains as answered. And you can *upvote* any answer that were useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Upgrade?

When you choose to upgrade your existing Ubuntu you will also upgrade the GNOME shell you had installed including all settings, and customizations.

The more you had altered your system from a vanilla Ubuntu the more you will have to redo all these steps in case you reinstall. This may not be an issue for you, but on some systems it can take rather long.

#### Reinstall?

A fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME remix will not install Unity and dependencies, so it will be somewhat leaner, and closer to a pure GNOME experience.

If you take extra care to **not format your HOME** you may also be able keep individual settings from your previous GNOME shell installation.

#### Now what to do?

At the end it is more or less your individual choice from your individual set up. A generally valid answer can not reasonably be given.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try an upgrade based on my current installation and see what happens. Worst case is that I'll have to go for a fresh install of UG 13.04 if it all goes badly wrong!

Comment: @RobertSwipe: yeah, that's a reasonable approach. Good luck! :)